# iphone image carousel

Tags: iphone, animation, core-animation

I hardly know how to explain my case other than to point to the excellent Absolute vodka app, Drink Spiration.

I am trying to make a carousel like image browsing with a little spice.  I would really like to find a simple core animation explanation on how to accomplish something like the above app.

I hope someone can help with this.  The solution doesn't have to be exactly the same, but just explain what is happening and it would be best if it was simple and no opengl.  Just something to point me in the right direction.  I don't think using just a scrollview with uiimageviews is enough.

Comment: I am also trying to implement carousel view by converting coverflow example but could not able to make it. Looking some other alternate.

Thanks,
Sunil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote something similar and its quite easy once you figure it out in your mind. All done justing using regular old views and animating transforms on them.

Say its 3 images on screen, and you can rotate new ones on and off ... then you will need 5 views set up (most simply just a UIImageView with a relevant image set). They are the currently selected image, the two either side of it and the ones that are, or will be animating on or off when the user flicks left or right.

Each of these 5 images has a position, an angle and an image. When the user flicks left or right each gets animated to the next position and angle, views that are about to come onscreen have their image updated to the next image in the set. If the user keeps on flicking in the same direction you simply reposition views on one side as they come off the other.

With this setup you can do lots of cool carousel like things very simply.